# Calling helper method from Class method: "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, helpermethods

I'm getting: `undefined method 'important_method' for #<Class:0xbee7b80>`

when I call: `User.some_class_method`

with:

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ApplicationHelper

  def self.some_class_method
    important_method()
  end

end


# helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def important_method()
    [...]
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include` is generally used to include code at the instance level, where `extend` is for the class level.  In this case, you'll want to look to have `User` `extend` `ApplicationHelper`.  I haven't tested this, but it might be that simple.

RailsTips has [a great write-up](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) on `include` vs. `extend` - I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I also found another source for this issue at: http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/09/20/concerning-yourself-with-active-support-concern/ and posted my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not DRY, but it works - change application_helper.rb to:

```
# helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  # define it and make it available as class method
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def important_method()
      [...]
    end
  end

  # define it and make it available as intended originally (i.e. in views)
  def important_method()
    [...]
  end

end
```